# Unit test Entity core mock data

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core, mocking

I am trying to set up unit test cases for a web api using .net Core 6 and Entity Framework. I want to add mock data for the "UseInMemoryDatabase("test")"

I am pretty rusty at EF and completely new to Entity Core. Code is posted below. I have two function I wrote to create a mock Tenant service and to create mock data to populate the in memory DB. When I try to run the test I get the error below that happens on the line:

context.PartCustomers?.AddRange(CreatePartCustomer());

where I am trying to add in the mock data for the in memory db. Am I misunderstanding how this is done?

Message=Services for database providers 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory', 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' have been registered in the service provider. Only a single database provider can be registered in a service provider. If possible, ensure that Entity Framework is managing its service provider by removing the call to 'UseInternalServiceProvider'. Otherwise, consider conditionally registering the database provider, or maintaining one service provider per database provider.

```cs
// Add mock/test services to the builder here
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddScoped(sp =>
                {
                    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase("Tests")
                    .UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp)
                    .Options;
                    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options, 
                                                                  MakeMockTenantService(),
                                                                  settingsOptions))
                    {
                        context.PartCustomers?.AddRange(CreatePartCustomer());
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                        // Replace SQLite with in-memory database for tests
                        return options;
                });
            });
```

Comment: So, further research on the error has pointed me to the article below which references how to do testing with EF core. It seems to say that using the in memory thing is not the way to do for testing. I am going to read through it and try and figure it out, but if anyone has some actual coded examples I would REALLY appreciate any time you can save me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/

Comment: [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/)

Comment: [Mocking Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2)

Comment: The first link is where I got my current example code and am getting an error. The second link appears to be an older entity framework not Entity Core. I am trying to get something working that will use the .net6 depedancy injection to inject a mock EF DB. And I am getting errors.